# createCriteria Java. Как передать переменную Var.class?

Tags: java, hibernate

Доброй ночи форумчане! 
Интересует такой вопрос:
Как через переменную или дженерик передавать в createCriteria скласс?
Ну что-то типа createCriteria(var.class)...

```
public List<T> readAll() {
    Session session = null;
    List<T> obj = null;
    try{
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        obj = session.createCriteria(T.class).list();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Всегда в области дженерика Т.class появляется ошибка "Unknown class type".
Может есть альтернатива? 
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее красивое решение, на мой взгляд, следующее:

Создайте базовый класс для DAO, от которого будут наследоваться все остальные классы. В нем определите необходимые методы. Должно получиться что то такое:

```
public class GeneralDAO<T>{

   public List<T> readAll(){
    ....        
   } 
 }

public class CatDAO extends GeneralDAO<Cat>{}
```

Теперь чтобы получить экземпляр класса `Class<T>type` необходимо в классе `GeneralDAO<T>` определить следующим образом конструктор:

```
 private final Class<T> type;

 public GenericHibernateDAO() {  
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()  
                            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];  
 }
```

Более [подробный пример](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects)

Comment: Да, действительно. Буду переделывать полностью архитектуру. В процессе стало понятно, что сущностей будет много и под каждый писать DAOIml - не вариант. 
За статью огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837203/3212712), передав класс в виде аргумента метода. То как вы хотите, похоже, просто нельзя, т.к. см ссылку выше:

```
public List<T> readAll(Class<T> type) {
    Session session = null;
    List<T> obj = null;
    try{
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        obj = session.createCriteria(type).list();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.